# How to read XML file using XmlSerializer C#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, xmlserializer

I have a problem when I want to read XML file by using XmlSerializer.
My xml file like follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<contents>
  <section id="1">   
    <element1>2</element1>
    <element2>1</element2>
    <idx>1</idx>  
    <idx>2</idx>  
    <idx>3</idx>    
  </section>

  <section id="2">
    <element1>2</element1>
    <element2>1</element2>    
  </section>

  <section id="3"/>
</contents>
```

Here are the classes:

```
 [Serializable()]
 public class section
 {
     [XmlAttribute("id")]
     public string id { get; set; }

     [XmlElement("element1")]
     public int element1 { get; set; }

     [XmlElement("element2")]
     public int element2 { get; set; }


     [XmlElement("idx")]
     public int[] idx { get; set; }


 }
     [Serializable()]
     [XmlRoot("contents")]
     public class contents
     {
         [XmlArray("section")]
         [XmlArrayItem("section", typeof(section))]
         public section[] section { get; set; }
     }
```

---

The Deserialize function:

```
             XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(contents));


             FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
             XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);


             contents i;


             i = (contents)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
             fs.Close();




             foreach (section p in i.section)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(p.element1);
             }
```

Why it doesn't work?
I had reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx but it seem not useful.
Please help me!!!!!

Comment: You've provided some good information, but this seems to be a duplicate.  In either case, it's usually a good idea to specify what specifically isn't working - an exception in serialization?  members not initialized as expected?  My guess is that you are having issues with the arrays, since they're not quite set up correctly.  See the linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

Usings...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Classes...(created from your XML using http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "section")]
    public class Section
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "element1")]
        public string Element1 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "element2")]
        public string Element2 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "idx")]
        public List<string> Idx { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "contents")]
    public class Contents
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "section")]
        public List<Section> Section { get; set; }
    }
```

Code...

```
        Contents dezerializedXML = new Contents();
        // Deserialize to object
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Contents));
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"xml.xml"))
        {
            dezerializedXML = (Contents)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        } // Put a break-point here, then mouse-over dezerializedXML
```

I put your XML in a file (xml.xml) and read it from there....

Comment: Oh mo, It is working like i want it to, thanks you very much <3